# Getting multidimensional array from json_decode

Tags: php, json, multidimensional-array

How do I access $result['products'] from this JSON response?

```
{"503380":{"response_code":"100","click_id":"10215bdfce7c","product_qty_30":"3","products[0][product_id]":"30","products[0][sku]":"ACMEROCKET","products[0][price]":"32.66"}}

$result = json_decode($result, 1);
```

Then when I do

```
print_r($result['products]);
```

I just get

```
Notice: Undefined index: products
```

But when I do

```
print_r($result);
```

I get

```
Array
(
    [503380] => Array
        (
            [response_code] => 100
            [click_id] => 10215bdfce7c
            [product_qty_30] => 3
            [products[0][product_id]] => 30
            [products[0][sku]] => ACMEROCKET
            [products[0][price]] => 32.66
        )

)
```

I noticed there were two ending brackets (]) after each products element but how do I make them accessible through

```
$result['products']
```

?

Comment: You data was inserted as String and not object/array

Comment: So its not a problem on my level, it's a problem with the JSON string that's being returned from the API I'm using?

Seems like there should be a way to turn them into an array, especially noticing how the products elements are ending with two brackets instead of one

Comment: I believe the data wasn't stored properly, yes, "products[0][sku]" vs "products":[{"sku":"ACMEROCKET", "price":32.66}]

Comment: Dump the contents of $result using:  echo '<pre>';var_dump($result);echo '</pre>';  Put that into a function while you're at it.  You'll easily see that the JSON data isn't properly encoded.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all.. Turns out it is simply the JSON being passed incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

It is incorrect JSON, but if you realy need you can try something like this:

```
$result = json_decode($json, true);
foreach($result[503380] as $key=>$value) {
    @eval("$" . $key . " = \"" . $value . "\";");
}
var_dump($products);
```

But it is very **BAD PRACTICE!** Because in json can be malicious code that is executed on your server.